# MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run tests on my `firm` microservice but am getting a test suite failed to run error "MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations". This occurs on  my `CompanyCancelledListener` event listener. Below is my code. I am running a test setup before each test that works for the other suites but I included the code for informational purposes.

**setup.ts**:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Firm, FirmDoc } from '../models/firm';
import { buildUser } from '../build-model/build-user';
import { buildFirm } from '../build-model/build-firm';

declare global {
  var rootsignin: () => Promise<string[]>;
  var signin: (firm?: FirmDoc, trig?: boolean) => Promise<string[]>;
}

jest.mock("../nats-wrapper");

let mongo: any;
beforeAll(async () => {
  jest.setTimeout(10000);
  process.env.JWT_KEY = "asdfasdf";
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

global.rootsignin = async () => {
  const email = "test@test.com";
  const name = 'Root User';
  const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
  const firmId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();

  const firm = await buildFirm(firmId, id, '@test.com');
  const user = await buildUser(id, firmId, '@test.com');

  const payload = {
    id: user.id,
    email,
    name,
    firmId: firm.id,
    firmAdmin: true,
    root: true,
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_KEY!);

  const session = { jwt: token };

  const sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session);

  const base64 = Buffer.from(sessionJSON).toString("base64");

  return [`session=${base64}`];
};

global.signin = async (firm?: FirmDoc, trig: boolean = false) => {
  let id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
  let id2;
  if (trig) {
    id2 = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
    id = id2;
  }
  const id3 = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();

  const newFirm = firm ? firm : await buildFirm(id3, id);

  let user = trig ? await buildUser(id, newFirm.id, '@newtest.com') : await buildUser(id, newFirm.id);

  const realFirm = await Firm.findOne({ _id: newFirm.id });
  
  if (realFirm && !realFirm.users.includes(user.id)) {
    realFirm.users.push(user.id);
    await realFirm.save();
  }

  const payload = {
    id: user.id,
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: 'Test Name',
    firmId: newFirm.id,
    firmAdmin: false,
    root: false,
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_KEY!);

  const session = { jwt: token };

  const sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session);

  const base64 = Buffer.from(sessionJSON).toString("base64");

  const cookie = [`session=${base64}`];
  return cookie;
};
```

**company-cancelled-listener.ts**:

```
import { Message } from "node-nats-streaming";
import { Subjects, Listener, CompanyCancelledEvent, CompanyStatus, BadRequestError } from "@mavata/common";
import { Company } from "../../models/company"
import { Firm } from '../../models/firm';
import { queueGroupName } from "./queue-group-name";
import { User } from "../../models/user";

export class CompanyCancelledListener extends Listener<CompanyCancelledEvent> {
  subject: Subjects.CompanyCancelled = Subjects.CompanyCancelled;
  queueGroupName = queueGroupName;

  async onMessage(data: CompanyCancelledEvent["data"], msg: Message) {
    const { id, version } = data;

    const company = await Company.findById(id);
    if (company) {
      company.status = CompanyStatus.Cancelled;
      await company.save();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Company not found with id ' + id)
    }

    const firm = await Firm.findCompanyAndDelete(id);

    company.users.forEach(async (user) => {
      await User.findCompanyAndDelete(company.id, user);
    });

    msg.ack();
  }
}
```

**(TEST) company-cancelled-listener.test.ts**:

```
import { Message } from "node-nats-streaming";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { CompanyCancelledEvent, CompanyStatus } from "@mavata/common";
import { CompanyCancelledListener } from "../company-cancelled-listener";
import { natsWrapper } from "../../../nats-wrapper";
import { Company } from "../../../models/company";
import { buildFirm } from "../../../build-model/build-firm";
import { buildUser } from "../../../build-model/build-user";
import { Firm } from "../../../models/firm";

const setup = async () => {
  const listener = new CompanyCancelledListener(natsWrapper.client);

  const firm = await buildFirm();
  const adminId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
  const user = await buildUser(adminId, firm.id);

  const data: CompanyCancelledEvent["data"] = {
    id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(),
    status: CompanyStatus.Cancelled,
    version: 1,
    name: "Test Company",
    adminId: user.id,
    firmId: firm.id,
    users: [user.id],
    permissions: [],
    connection: false,
    last: false
  };

  const company = Company.build({
    id: data.id,
    version: data.version,
    status: data.status,
    name: data.name,
    adminId: data.adminId,
    firmId: data.firmId,
    users: data.users
  });

  await company.save();

  await Firm.addCompany(company.id, firm.id);
  // firm.companies.push(company.id);
  // await firm.save();

  // create a fake message object
  // @ts-ignore
  const msg: Message = {
    ack: jest.fn(),
  };

  return { listener, data, msg };
};

it("creates and saves a Company", async () => {
  const { listener, data, msg } = await setup();

  await listener.onMessage(data, msg);

  const company = await Company.findById(data.id);

  expect(company).toBeDefined();
  expect(company!.name).toEqual(data.name);
  expect(company!.status).toEqual(data.status);
  expect(`${company!.adminId}`).toEqual(`${data.adminId}`);
  expect(`${company!.firmId}`).toEqual(`${data.firmId}`);
});

it("acks the message", async () => {
  const { data, listener, msg } = await setup();

  await listener.onMessage(data, msg);

  expect(msg.ack).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**(MODEL) company.ts**:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { updateIfCurrentPlugin } from 'mongoose-update-if-current';
import { CompanyStatus } from '@mavata/common';

interface CompanyAttrs {
  id: string;
  status?: CompanyStatus;
  version?: number;
  name: string;
  adminId: string;
  firmId: string;
  users?: string[];
}

export interface CompanyDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  status: CompanyStatus;
  version: number;
  name: string;
  adminId: string;
  firmId: string;
  users: string[];
  connection: boolean;
  last: boolean;
}

interface CompanyModel extends mongoose.Model<CompanyDoc> {
  build(attrs: CompanyAttrs): CompanyDoc;
  findByEvent(event: {
    id: string;
    version: number;
  }): Promise<CompanyDoc | null>;
  findUserAndDelete(id: string, companyId?: string): CompanyDoc;
}

const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: CompanyStatus.Created,
      required: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    adminId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    firmId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Firm",
      required: true,   // BEM TO DO
    },
    users: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      default: [],
      required: true
    }],
    connection: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: true
    },
    last: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: true
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
  }
);

companySchema.set('versionKey', 'version');
companySchema.plugin(updateIfCurrentPlugin);

companySchema.statics.findByEvent = (event: { id: string; version: number }) => {
  return Company.findOne({
    _id: event.id,
    version: event.version - 1,
  });
};

companySchema.statics.build = (attrs: CompanyAttrs) => {
  const v = attrs.version || 0;
  const s = attrs.status || CompanyStatus.Created;

  return new Company({
    _id: attrs.id,
    name: attrs.name,
    version: v,
    status: s,
    adminId: attrs.adminId,
    firmId: attrs.firmId,
    users: attrs.users || [],
  });
};

companySchema.statics.findUserAndDelete = async (id: string, companyId?: string) => {
  let company;

  if (companyId) {
    company = await Company.findOneAndUpdate({ id: companyId }, {
      $pull: { users: id }
    });
  } else {
    company = await Company.findOneAndUpdate({ users: id }, {
      $pull: { users: id }
    });
  }
  
  if (!company) {
    throw new Error('Company not found associated with user of id ' + id);
  }

  await company.save();

  return company;
};

const Company = mongoose.model<CompanyDoc, CompanyModel>('Company', companySchema);

export { Company };
```